# Generate ordered list widget with gwt-dnd

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop, uibinder

I'm trying to generate an ordered list of widgets. 
My goal is to make a menu builder [gwt-dnd](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/), I'm trying to do this as the example https://gwt-dnd.appspot.com/#InsertPanelExample, I get a two-dimensional array with the columns and elements they contain.
For example:

MenuItem  // ui contains: id, label, url, order, List MenuItem childrens

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________
| Menu Item order 0, column draggable    |  Menu item order 1 coldrag     |   etc
|                                        |                                |
| ______________________________________ |  _____________________________ |
| | MenuItem order 0, item draggable   | |  | MenuItem order 0          | |
| |                                    | |  |                           | |                 
| |                                    | |  |                           | |               
| |____________________________________| |  |___________________________| |
|                                        |                                |
|                                        |                                |
|                                        |                                |
| ______________________________________ |                                |
| | MenuItem order 1, item draggable   | |                                |
| |                                    | |                                |
| |                                    | |                                |
| |____________________________________| |                                |
|                                        |                                |
|                                        |                                |
|                                        |                                |
| ______________________________________ |                                |
| | MenuItem order 2, item draggable   | |                                |
| |                                    | |                                |
| |                                    | |                                |
| |____________________________________| |                                |
|                                                                         |
|
```

The problem is I do not know how to apply the order to each item and generate an array with the result. 
See if you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created something very similar to this but I used gwtquery's dnd plugin written by julien drameaux. I created something very similar to what you are using. Keep in mind gwtquery is a gwt port of jquery and does not use external js files and does not wrap another js library. It is very fast and efficient. I used gwt-dnd in the past but found that gwtquery-dnd plugin was much better for newer widgets like the CellWidgets.

I used the portlet example to start with which was very simple and expanded on it later on.

Here is the portlet example along with others.

http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/branches/droppable_1_0/demo/GwtPortletSample/GwtPortletSample.html

Here is the documentation which is very good.

https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers#DragAndDropCellList_class

BTW here is my example that uses a modified version of the portlet that allows ordering. It is also an editor so that I can flush the widgets using the gwt editor framework.

```
public class EditableDNDCellList<T> extends Composite implements IsEditor<HasDataEditor<T>> {

    private class DropHandler implements DropEventHandler, OverDroppableEventHandler, OutDroppableEventHandler, DragEventHandler, DragStartEventHandler, DragStopEventHandler {

        private boolean isHover;
        // position in the cell of the place holder
        private int placeHolderPosition = 0;
        // the place holder is inserted just before this element
        private Element insertPoint;

        private GQuery placeHolder = $("<div id='cellPlaceHolder'></div>");

        public DropHandler() {

            placeHolder.css(CSS.BACKGROUND_COLOR.with(RGBColor.rgb("#B5D5FF")));
            placeHolder.css(CSS.BORDER.with(Length.px(1), BorderStyle.DASHED, RGBColor.BLACK));
            placeHolder.css(CSS.WIDTH.with(Length.pct(100)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDragStop(DragStopEvent event) {
            Element draggedCell = event.getDraggable();
            $(draggedCell).css(CSS.DISPLAY.with(Display.BLOCK));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
            Element draggedCell = event.getDraggable();
            $(draggedCell).css(CSS.DISPLAY.with(Display.NONE));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrag(DragEvent event) {
            if (isHover) {
                maybeMovePlaceHolder(event.getHelper());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onOutDroppable(OutDroppableEvent event) {
            reset();
        }

        @Override
        public void onOverDroppable(OverDroppableEvent event) {
            Element dragHelper = event.getDragHelper();
            Element draggingCell = event.getDraggable();
            T operation = event.getDroppableData();

            placeHolder.height($(dragHelper).height());
            // attach the placeholder just before the dragging cell
            insertPoint = draggingCell;
            placeHolderPosition = cellList.getVisibleItems().indexOf(operation);
            movePlaceHolder();

            // enable listening on drag event
            isHover = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
            T operation = event.getDraggableData();

            asEditor().getList().remove(operation);
            asEditor().getList().add(placeHolderPosition, operation);
            //asEditor().getList().set(placeHolderPosition, operation);
            reset();
        }

        /**
         * reset the state of this object
         */
        private void reset() {
            isHover = false;
            // remove the place holder
            placeHolder.remove();
            insertPoint = null;
        }

        /**
         * Check if we have to move the place holder
         * 
         * @param draggableHelper
         */
        private void maybeMovePlaceHolder(Element draggableHelper) {
            Element newCellAfterPlaceHolder = resolveCurrentInsertPoint(draggableHelper);

            if (newCellAfterPlaceHolder != null && newCellAfterPlaceHolder.equals(insertPoint)) {
                // placeHolder must not move
                return;
            }

            insertPoint = newCellAfterPlaceHolder;
            movePlaceHolder();

        }

        /**
         * insert the place holder before the insertPoint element if this last
         * is not null. Otherwise set the place holder at the end of the
         * CellList
         */
        private void movePlaceHolder() {
            placeHolder.remove();
            if (insertPoint != null) {
                placeHolder.insertBefore(insertPoint);
            } else {
                GQuery allCells = $(".operationCell", cellList);

                int last = allCells.elements().length;
                // insert the place holder at the end
                placeHolder.insertAfter(allCells.get(last));
                //Window.alert("ADDED THE VALUE");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Return the first cell having its absolute top property just greater
         * than drag helper. The place holder should be inserted just before
         * this cell.
         * 
         * @param draggableHelper
         * @return
         */
        private Element resolveCurrentInsertPoint(Element draggableHelper) {
            GQuery allCells = $(".operationCell", cellList);

            if (allCells.isEmpty()) {
                // no cells, the placeholder should just be added in the begin
                // of the cell
                // list
                return null;
            }

            // compare absoluteTop of the draggable with absoluteTop of all
            // cells
            int draggableAbsoluteTop = draggableHelper.getAbsoluteTop();

            int i = 0;

            for (Element cell : allCells.elements()) {
                // workaround for issue 79
                if ($(cell).parent().visible()) {
                    int cellAbsoluteTop = cell.getAbsoluteTop();
                    if (cellAbsoluteTop > draggableAbsoluteTop) {
                        placeHolderPosition = i;
                        return cell;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
            placeHolderPosition = i;

            return null;
        }
    }


    /**
     * This is our editor used to edit our ScriptInputProxy classes.
     */
    private HasDataEditor<T> editor = null;

    private final DragAndDropCellList<T> cellList;

    private AbsolutePanel container = new AbsolutePanel();

    private DroppableWidget<DragAndDropCellList<T>> dropPanel;
    private DropHandler dragHandler = new DropHandler();


    public EditableDNDCellList(Cell<T> cell) {
        initWidget(container);

        cellList = new DragAndDropCellList<T>(cell);
        dropPanel = new DroppableWidget<DragAndDropCellList<T>>(cellList);

        DraggableOptions options = new DraggableOptions();

        options.setHelper(HelperType.CLONE);
        options.setAppendTo("body");
        options.setOpacity(0.8f);
        options.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        options.setAxis(AxisOption.Y_AXIS);
        options.setRevert(RevertOption.ON_INVALID_DROP);
        cellList.setDraggableOptions(options);

        dropPanel.addOverDroppableHandler(dragHandler);
        dropPanel.addOutDroppableHandler(dragHandler);
        dropPanel.addDropHandler(dragHandler);

        cellList.addDragHandler(dragHandler);
        cellList.addDragStartHandler(dragHandler);
        cellList.addDragStopHandler(dragHandler);

        editor = HasDataEditor.of(cellList);
        container.add(dropPanel);
    }

    public void setMaxListSize(int maxListSize) {
        cellList.setPageSize(maxListSize);
    }

    @Override
    public HasDataEditor<T> asEditor() {
        return editor;
    }

    public CellList<T> getCellList() {
        return cellList;
    }
}
```